# Is Kafka with CQRS is a microservice approach?

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka, microservices, cqrs

Is Kafka with CQRS is a microservice approach ?or else kafka and CQRS are separate terms that describes the patterns in architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka is product that provides you with an scalable implementation of a queue.
CQRS is a pattern which talks about how you can separate calls that update databases from those which just reads stuff from DB.

Both of them have no direct association with microservices, which itself just talks about one of way of writing your software. It gives basic guidelines on how to break your software into pieces that might help you develop, deploy and scale them easily.

To answer you question, you can make use of both of them in microservices or you can use them even if you do not have microservices.

Answer (score 0):

You should have asked is "Kafka better suited for CQRS development".

Unlike typical queues, in Kafka you can save messages based on 'time period, number of items' etc. If you store all the events in Kafka from beginning you can use it for CQRS.

Unlike in other queues where messages are deleted as soon as they are consumed kafka can keep them forever instead.